# I want my custom libraries to behave like thos of Laravel's

Tags: php, laravel

You know in Laravel classes are used on the fly. Such as :

```
Auth::login()
```

I have added my own custom library `HTMLER()` how then I can make to behave like Laravel? I just need my function to be instanciated already without me to instanciate it on every attempt.

For instance I have a function `get_files()` which I want to be used :

```
HTMLER::get_files()
```

or `HTML->get_files()`

Whenever I want than having to make an instance of the class every time:

```
new HTMLER();
$x->get_files()
```

Too awkward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your class already, so it should be fairly easy.

Ensure your class is in a directory that is being autoloaded.  You can see the autoloaded directories in your `composer.json` file.  Or you can add another directory if you wish.

## Service Provider

Create a service provider for your class.  Again, be sure it's somewhere that is being autoloaded.  This is basically for telling Laravel how to get your class when you need it.

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HtmlerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Htmler', function()
        {
            return new Htmler; // Name of your class, be sure to include the namespace     if you are using one.
        });
    }
}
```

Be sure to add your service provider into the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

`'Htmler',`

## Facade

Next, you can create your Facade.  (Autoloaded again).  Telling Laravel how you want to be able to call your class when you need it.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Htmler extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'Htmler'; }

}
```

## Alias

If you wish, you could also create an alias for your Facade so you can use whichever name you want to call it...  Just add to the `aliases` array in `config/app.php`.  Easy example.

`'HTMLER' => 'Htmler',`

These are pretty much from the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/facades and http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers

Answer (score 1):

Here's the tutorial I followed when I started doing this: http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4